# Qgis Python Plugin leaves orphaned variables in RAM, even after plugin reload

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, memory-layer

My python plugin for QGIS 2.18 opens files with millions of features.
To convert them in Qgis readable format, I run through several external python libs, one of them is a R-Tree tool, consuming 10G of RAM. Then I create a memory layer and add a million points or triangles. All intermediate steps and their variables are useless now and can be deleted. So far so good.

But if I remove the layer (or all layers completely) the RAM is still full, even after deactivating / reloading the plugin! Even after using "del(biggest_RAM_eating_variables)" or gc.collect().

RAM is only freed after stopping QGIS itself. The problem doesn't occur with the reader outside of QGIS.

- Any ideas how to cleanup the RAM during QGIS runtime?
- Or any ideas what might be the real problem?
- Or how to run the plugin in an external, killable thread?

Comment: What library do you use for the rtree? Seems like this is where the issue lies.